# Unable to connect to LocalDB during webhosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using `asp.net identity` with `EF data first` approach. Everything is working fine on localhost. I have hosted my website on appharbor. All of my controllers actions and webapi is working fine except `AccountController`. When a user tries to signup it gives the `Internal server error`. The details of error is: 
[image]

**Note:** My database queries are working fine. It means there is no issue in connection string.

And to enable remote connections `SQL Server Network Configuration` does not has the option `Protocols for SQLEXPRESS`
[image]

How can I tackle this issue?

**Update:**
My connection strings in `web.config` are:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=b1ad1f3e-1ab5-4169-93f8-a5ae006f3e4e.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;Database=8a5ae006f3e4e;User ID=namucclqps;Password=54nWBkCfURyMzYfhbu8NUQb6PEZUsWcoN;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

**Update 2:**
I installed `SQL Server Management Studio`. Then I hosted my website on appharbor and installed add-on `SQL Server`. Then using following info I connected to Server.[image]

Then added tables in `SQL Server Management Studio` and changed connection string in `web.config` and published website.

Comment: Actually there *is* an error in the connection string and that's exactly what the error is saying -  it can't connect to the server. It even explains that you tried to use a LocalDB connection string when LocalDB is *not* installed. Are you using a *different* connection string for user management perhaps?

Comment: I have manually entered data in tables in `SQL Server Management Studio` and queries are working fine and data is retrieved. Is there still a chance that the error is in connection string?

Comment: SSMS has nothing to do with the connection string you stored in your web.config. In any case, the error couldn't be *more* explicit - you are using a LocalDB connection string and there's no LocalDB runtime installed on the web server. Either the connection string is wrong and doesn't point to your database, or it is correct and you added the data to a database the site knows nothing about

Comment: Please post the connection string in the question. The rest of the code, screenshots aren't necessary

Comment: updated question please have a look

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please give some suggestions what else I should do to solve this issue

Comment: I've already mentioned the only solution. Fix the connection string in web.config. Your `DefaultConnection` contains `Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;` which *only* works if you have LocalDB installed. Your screenshot though shows a *different* connection string provided by your hoster. Replace it with the connection string provided by your hoster

Comment: "SQL Server database on web hoster"? I am not trying to attach database file. I created tables on `SSMS` that acts as server. right? And I used the connection string provided by `SQL Server` add-on.

Comment: Please. Check what you actually posted as the `DefaultConnection` in your web.config. It says `Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835;Integrated Security=True`. That string is trying to attach to a database file using LocalDB.

Comment: There is really no reason to post any comment unless you change the connection string in your web.config first. Perhaps AppHarbor needs some trick to inject its own connection string, which is covered in the documentation.

Comment: I have removed `DefaultConnection` line from web.config but error is still there and I'm following conventions in `Entities` connection string.

Answer (score 0):

LocalDB is only a thing inside Visual Studio. There's no way to even get it on a production server. You need to install some version of SQL Server and then create your database and tables there.

After that, leave the original connection string inside Web.config alone, and instead, add a transform in `Web.Release.config` that changes the connection string to the one for your production SQL Server instance of your database. Finally, when publishing your site, select the "Release" configuration. The Web.config will then be transformed during publishing and will reference the production database once the site is deployed.

Comment: I'm using `SQL Server Management Studio`. I updated the question please have a look

Comment: "LocalDB is only a thing inside Visual Studio. There's no way to even get it on a production server." No that's not true at all. But for the OP's purposes, using AppHarbour, it effectively is because they only provide access to "normal" SQL server instances.